# in javascript, call each function in array with a callback using forEach?

Tags: javascript, recursion

An array of functions, `[fn1,fn2,...]`, each "returns" through a callback, passing an optional error.  If an error is returned through the callback, then subsequent functions in the array should not be called.

```
// one example function
function fn1( callback ) {
   <process>
   if( error ) callback( errMsg );
   else callback();
   return;
}

// go through each function until fn returns error through callback
[fn1,fn2,fn3,...].forEach( function(fn){
  <how to do this?>
} );
```

This can be solved [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869872/in-javascript-what-are-best-practices-for-executing-multiple-asynchronous-functi), but nonetheless would love the syntactic dexterity to use approach.

Can this be done?

---

as per correct answer:

```
[fn1,fn2,fn3,...].every( function(fn) {
  var err;
  fn.call( this, function(ferr) { err = ferr; } );
  if( err ) {
     nonblockAlert( err );
     return false;
  }
  return true;
} );
```

seems this has room for simplification.

for me, much better approach to solve this type of problem - it's flatter, the logic more accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and if you can use JavaScript 1.6 (e.g. this is for NodeJS), then you could use the `every` function.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

> every executes the provided callback function once for each element
>   present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a false
>   value. If such an element is found, the every method immediately
>   returns false. Otherwise, if callback returned a true value for all
>   elements, every will return true.

So, something like:

```
[fn1, fn2, fn3, ...].every(function(fn) {
    // process
    if (error) return false;
    return true;
});
```

Again, this requires JavaScript 1.6